# Unable to start ubuntu after installing updates - Stuck at 'Try (hd0,0)'

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on the same hard drive as my Windows 8.1 OS, on its own partition. The installation went without any hickups.

After that I used EasyBCD on my windows system to create a new boot entry for Ubuntu (Using GRUB 2).

Again, this worked fine, and starting either system via the boot menu also worked as it should.

I then let the auto-updater for Ubuntu install its updates and ever since that I cannot start Ubuntu anymore. If I try, it leaves me with this message (Right after choosing Ubuntu from the boot menu):

```
Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,2): Extended:
Try (hd0,3): invalid or null
Try (hd0,4): non-MS: skip
Try (hd0,5): Extended:
Try (hd0,5): EXT2:
```

Nothing else happens after that. Starting windows still works fine however.

I've check the partitions with the disk management utility in windows, and everything seems to be in order:

http://puu.sh/gnu2H/e8f1754b20.png

The two unnamed partitions are the /swap and root-partitions for Ubuntu.

What could be causing this sudden change? Everything was fine until I ran the autoupdater.

I've seen a similar question on here, but the problem there was with an UEFI-BIOS (Which I don't have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use liveCD, find partition where ubuntu is installed (use Gparted -similar partitioning program. Mount the partition (Ext4-usually):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

(where partition name is sda1 else sdb1, sda2 etc...).

Now bind

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Then

```
sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sda
```

(notice sda not sda1 - else disk which is bootable)

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Also you may check `/etc/default/grub` using liveCD (gedit/kate) after mounting the Ext4 partition for any incompatibilities.

I have not used windows for a long time. May be Win8 does not allow GRUB2 entries, I have no experience with EasyBCD. ref to the help/man pages of EasyBCD, you may find something there.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have your name twice under your post? You edit your post if you have additional information, commenting on your own post should be reserved for non-essential/non-relevant material

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick on the first try! I would give this an up-vote, but I don't have enough reputation for that yet...

Comment: thank you for sharing this,  worked absolutely great for me. now i m greeted with two startup screen,  one from grub and when i select windows 7 then it shows the BCD Menu.  is there a way of removing the BCD menu completely.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after updating my Windows 7... fixed by resetting easy BCD. I had to clear all preset menu options and then re-add the new entries pointing to the correct drive